# How to add content with select tag without refreshing the page(AJAX)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I am trying to make a page when someone clicks on a option in the select form, another select form appears then another without having to refresh the page. I know you use AJAX for not refreshing but my code is somehow not working when tried.

HTML

```
<div id="example">
<select id="foo">
<option value="">lets make another</option>
<option value="index.html">Demographic</option>
<option value="index.html">Crime</option>
<option value="index.html">School</option>

</select>
   </div>
   <div id="result">
   </div>
```

javascript(AJAX)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#example').on('click', 'button.switch', function() {
    $.ajax('AjaxLoadedContent.html')
    .done(function(response){
    $('#result').html(response);
    });
});
});
```

Content thats suppose to load(Another select form)

```
<select id="foo">
<option value="">Pick a site</option>
<option value="index.html">Demographic</option>
<option value="index.html">Crime</option>
<option value="index.html">School</option>

</select>
```

But whats wrong??

Comment: Where is `button.switch`? And is Ajax really required here? It seems that this could be done with all local code.

Comment: Yes, if you don't need to get any additional data from the server why not bind your lists and just show/filter the contents using JS?

Comment: What do you mean by binding the list? @Goose

Comment: By binding I just mean building the `select` lists with your data included. Build each of the lists, hide the ones that aren't being used. When the user makes a selection in the first list, show the second list and filter the options if needed, etc.

Answer (score 0):

As @Goose said in the comments, instead of using an Ajax call you could hide the select boxes and show them based on the value of the shown select option, as shown below:

### HTML

```
<div id="example">
    <select id="foo">
        <option value="">lets make another</option>
        <option value="demographic">Demographic</option>
        <option value="crime">Crime</option>
        <option value="school">School</option>
    </select>
    <select id="demographic" class="toggle">
        <option value="">Demographic</option>
        <option value="d1">d1</option>
        <option value="d2">d2</option>
        <option value="d3">d3</option>
    </select>
    <select id="crime" class="toggle">
        <option value="">Crime</option>
        <option value="c1">c1</option>
        <option value="c2">c2</option>
        <option value="c3">c3</option>
    </select>
    <select id="school" class="toggle">
        <option value="">School</option>
        <option value="s1">s1</option>
        <option value="s2">s2</option>
        <option value="s3">s3</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

### CSS

```
.toggle {
    display:none;
}
```

### JS

```
$('#foo').on('change', function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    $('.toggle').hide();
    $('#'+val).show();
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/367TK/)

Comment: When I click on one of the options, it takes me to a Object not found Url page? @LorenPosen

Comment: Which option? @CamTheArtist

Answer (score 0):

If your content is fairly static, I'd use the following code that doesn't invoke additional http calls:

HTML:

```
<div id="example">
    <select id="foo">
        <option value="">lets make another</option>
        <option value="">Demographic</option>
        <option value="">Crime</option>
        <option value="">School</option>
    </select>
 </div>
 <div id="result">
     <select id="foo">
        <option value="">Pick a site</option>
        <option value="">Demographic</option>
        <option value="">Crime</option>
        <option value="">School</option>
    </select>
 </div>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $("#result").hide();
    $("#foo").click(function() {
        $("#result").show();
    });
});
```

Let me know if it helps. Cheers!